# Flags with web services

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, flags

I have a flag attribute enumeration that is behind a web service as follows:

```
[Serializable,Flags]
public enum AccessLevels
{
    None = 0,
    Read = 1,
    Write = 2,
    Full = Read | Write
}
```

My problem is the consumer of my web service does not have the original constant values of the enum. The resulting proxy class client side has something that amounts to this:

```
{
   None = 1,
   Read = 2,
   Write = 4,
   Full = 8
}
```

And thus when the consumer is checking for "Read" access this will be false even when "testItem" is "Full"

```
((testItem & Svc.Read) == Svc.Read)
```

How can I properly provide flags over a web service?

EDIT:

According to [this](http://ikriv.com:8765/en/prog/info/dotnet/WebServices_and_Enums.html) article it may not be possible to do what I am looking to do. Ivan Krivyakov states

> Imperfect Transparency of Enums
>
> It turns out that enums are not as
>   transparent as we'd like them to be.
>   There are three sticky issues:
>
> 1. If server-side code declares an enum and assigns specific numeric
>      values to its members, these values
>      will not be visible to the client.
> 2. If server-side code declares a [Flags] enum with "compound" mask
>      values (as in White = Red|Green|Blue),
>      it is not properly reflected on the
>      client side.
> 3. If server or client transmits an "illegal" value which is outside of
>      the scope of the enum, it causes an
>      exception in XML de-serializer on the
>      other side.

So I wonder if this is just a limitation and is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done extensive research on this and found that it is not possible to serialize enumeration constants through a web service. Note that to accomplish your goal you don't need the enumerations None or Full. These two enumerations can be implied with read / write combination:

You could assume full access if your AccessLevels = Read | Write
   and none if your AccessLevels = 0 [nothing]

Your enumerations would look like this:

```
[Serializable,Flags]
public enum AccessLevels
{
    Read = 1,
    Write = 2
}
```

Comment: I am thinking that this is the route the I may need to take here. I would really like to be able to have the "None" option spelled out for my users however.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and got round it by adding another web service to return the currect flag values first.

Those then became the values I used in the compare.

Might not be the cleanest solution but it works.

Edit:

My original answer suggested that the values are passed across as a separate web service rather than within an enum.

However, poking around, it appears that an enumeration of 0,1,2 being mapped to 1,2,4 across a web service (even that the [Flags] attribute is set) is a common problem.

The solution suggested by a number of people is to modify the original enumeration definition and start from 1 rather than 0.

Answer (score 0):

Flags should be multiples of two, and in your case your flags are (0,1,2,3).
Try change your definition of the struct to:

```
[Serializable,Flags]
public enum AccessLevels{    
None = 1,    
Read = 2,    
Write = 4,    
Full = Read | Write}
```

And see if it works better.

(I hope Im not making a fool of myself, its late and Im on my way to the bed.. )

Comment: That still doesn't work. I've seen this problem before. With the numbering you mentioned your consumer will still see the following:

public enum AccessLevels 
{        
        None = 1,        
        Read = 2,
        Write = 4,
        Full = 8,
}

Comment: @Rorzilla yes that is indeed the case still. 
@Stefan I can "fix" it by removing the "Full" and "None" then the proxy class will become Read = 1 and Write = 2 but I would still like to provide the user with the none option so they don't have to "just know" something and dont have to use a value of 0

Comment: @Stefan - No, flags should be individual bits, of which 1 is the first. None should *always* be defined as 0 because that means there are no bits set. If None = 1 then what is 0? ReallyNone?

Comment: @Greg, sounds fair. I have seen 0 being used as "Default" in some cases though.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to provide a more verbose class instead of the enum e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class AccessPermission{
 public boolean None{get;set;}
 public boolean Read{get;set;}
 public boolean Write{get;set;}
 public boolean Full{get;set;}

 public AccessPermission(AccessLevels level){
  None = false;
  Read = false;
  Write = false;
  Full = false;

  switch(level){
  case AccessLevels.None:
   break;
  case AccessLevels.Read:
   Read = true;
   break;
  case AccessLevels.Write:
   Write = true;
   break;
  case AccessLevels.Full:
   Read = true;
   Write = true;
   Full = true;
   break;
  }
 }
}
```

The other option I can see is providing a method in what ever language they are using to successfully interoperate the integer you are sending. The flag operator means that c# does bit masking to find if a individual flag is marked

```
0001 -> None
0010 -> Read
0100 -> Write
0110 -> Full
```

so to check for any permission you should see if that bit is set

```
public static boolean CanRead(int accessLevel){
 return (accessLevel | 2) > 0 // return true if read bit set, using bitwise or
}

public static boolean CanWrite(int accessLevel){
 return (accessLevel | 4) > 0 // return true of write bit set.
}
```

Please note this second solution is more fragile, if you change the definition of accessLevels you client will silently miss behave.