# Flex, .NET Web Service and Numeric Enums

Tags: .net, apache-flex, web-services

We're using Flex 3 to consume a .NET Web Service. The web service uses an enum and we use Flex Builder to automatically generate the web service objects. Here is the .NET web service enum definition:

```
 /// <summary>
   /// User type
   /// </summary>
   public enum UserTypeEnum
   {
       Admin = 1,
       User = 3,
       Manager = 4
   }
```

When Flex generates the web service objects, it treats them as strings instead of integer values.

```
[Inspectable(category="Generated values", enumeration="Admin, User, Manager", type="String")]
public var _UserTypeEnum:String;public function toString():String
{
return _UserTypeEnum.toString();
}
```

When we get data from the web service, any property that uses this enumeration is Null instead of 'admin' or '1'. Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: did you ever get this working? I'm in the same situation but I dont really care about the numerical values, just want it to be populated and not always null

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that there are issues with enumerations and web services.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505617/flags-with-web-services/505628#505628).

- Should be using [Serializable,Flags] in web service.
- Flags should be multiples of two
- The enumeration definition should start from 1 rather than 0.

Comment: Minor pedantry I know, but *powers* of two surely, not simple multiples... :)

Comment: `[Serializable]` is ignored by XML Serialization.

Answer (score 0):

[There are some bugs listed at Adobe re: Flex 3 and enum's in WSDL](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&rlz=1T4HPIA_en&q=+site:bugs.adobe.com+FLEX+wsdl+enum) .. Are you sure you have the latest update ?

Answer (score 0):

In the languages derived from C (C#, C++, Java), an `enum` is effectively a set of named integral values.

There is no corresponding concept in XML Schema, therefore there is no such concept in web services.

Before you or anyone else mentions the `<xs:enumeration/>` facet, that's not what it's for. `<xs:enumeration/>` provides a list (an enumeration) of the possible lexical values for a type. There is no way to associate numbers with those lexical values. The following `enum`:

```
public enum Enumeration1
{
    E1a = 1,
    E1b = 2,
    E1c = 4
}
```

becomes the following XML Schema:

```
<s:simpleType name="Enumeration1">
    <s:restriction base="s:string">
        <s:enumeration value="E1a"/>
        <s:enumeration value="E1b"/>
        <s:enumeration value="E1c"/>
    </s:restriction>
</s:simpleType>
```

Note the absence of 1, 2, or 4.

All this says is that an element or attribute of this type will be a string, and may have one of the values "E1a", "E1b", or "E1c".

If a client proxy is built from a WSDL with such schema, and if the proxy code generator is smart enough, it may decide that this was originally a programming language `enum`. In this case, it would create the type as

```
public enum Enumeration1
{
    E1a,
    E1b,
    E1c
}
```

Since it has no access to the integers.