# Using flags as a three-state parameter

Tags: c#

I would like to pass an argument that says "all", "valid" or "invalid". Instead of going with a nullable bool, I thought that I'd give `Flags` a shot.

Since I've never used it before, I would like you to sort a few questions out for me:

```
[Flags]
public enum Options
{
    Valid,
    Invalid
}

private void Foo(Options options)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("valid: {0} {1}", 
    (options & Options.Valid) == Options.Valid, 
     options.HasFlag(Options.Valid)));

    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("invalid: {0} {1}", 
    (options & Options.Invalid) == Options.Invalid, 
     options.HasFlag(Options.Invalid)));

    Debug.WriteLine("---");
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Foo(Options.Valid | Options.Invalid);
    Foo(Options.Invalid);
    Foo(Options.Valid);
}

/*

Output:

valid: True True
invalid: True True
---
valid: True True
invalid: True True
---
valid: True True
invalid: False False

*/
```

As you can see, this doesn't give me the desired result. What I would like to know is if either "valid", "invalid" or both flags are set. How would I accomplish that?

Comment: How can something be `Valid` as well as `InValid` ? Sounds like oxymoron. Btw for flags to work your enum values to be in power of 2.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It's a validation where the users sometimes wants to see all the valid results as well

Comment: Also [Flags] shows you are using it in this way but it isn't actually required to use the attribute to do so.

Comment: @CRice yes and no: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902967/what-does-the-flags-attribute-really-do

Comment: @Johan be aware that enums start with 0, and your tests failing is due to the nature of "power of 2"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For flags you have to assign values so that the boolean operations work as expected:

```
[Flags]
public enum Options
{
    Valid = (1<<0), // 1
    Invalid = (1<<1), // 2
    All = Valid | Invalid
}
```

Otherwise your values will be assigned automatically, which would result in `Valid=0` and `Invalid=1`.

As you can see the `Valid` and `Invalid` are assigned power of 2 values (eg. 1,2,4,8...). This is needed for the flag test operations to work correctly, as they rely on simple [binary operations on the enum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93744/most-common-c-sharp-bitwise-operations-on-enums).

To check if both flags are set use:

```
options.HasFlag(Options.Valid | Options.Invalid)
```

or

```
options.HasFlag(Options.All)
```

Comment: I tend to do it rather like `1 << 0`, `1 << 1`, so that math gets easier (and the bit-position more obvious) ... And combined states rather like `All = Valid | Invalid` ( just in case the bit changes, and again: not doing the math) ...

Comment: I see. And if I want to skip `All`? `options.HasFlag(Options.Invalid | Options.Valid)`?

Comment: @Johan what do you mean by skip?

Comment: How would I check if both `Valid` and `Invalid` is set, without making use of a third flag?

Comment: @Johan `options.HasFlag(Options.Invalid) && options.HasFlag(Options.Valid)` ... but for convenience (= less typing) introduction of a combined state is preferred

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Ok. How would I check if both `Valid` and `Invalid` is set without making use of `HasFlags()`?

Comment: @Johan bit-shifting?! ... c'mon, lmgtfy: eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93744/most-common-c-sharp-bitwise-operations-on-enums

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Thanks, wasn't aware of the term

Comment: @thumbmunkeys you should think about introducing `0`-value for failed conversions, and I **strongly encourage** you to state that the values have to be a power of 2 (due to the *bitish* nature of the shifting/value/whatsoever stuff)

Comment: @Johan just to be precise: bit-shifting is not the specific term for checking if a certain value is contained. the whole thing with `[Flags]` is covered by: shift operators and bitwise operators = bitwise operations